# Is there any way to implement linked list using classes and objects instead of pointers?

Tags: c++, class, oop, data-structures, linked-list

Is there any way to implement a linked list in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) using classes and objects instead of pointers?

I want to use the object-oriented programming approach.

Comment: Sure - just create an object of class `std::list`

Comment: What makes you think that use of pointers cannot be object oriented?

Comment: You could claim that `std::reference_wrapper<T>` is not a pointer and use that instead, but let's face it, it's still basically a pointer.

Comment: @JeJo is it though? I've gone through the first page of results and every implementation that came up is either broken, outdated, or both.

Comment: "Object oriented" doesn't mean what you think it means. In particular it definitely doesn't mean "no pointers".

Comment: Pointers are objects. Only references and functions are non-object types.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik nitpick: `std::list` is not a class.

Comment: By definition, each node in a linked list has a pointer or index to the next node.  The pointer could be an offset relative to some base pointer.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a more straightforward approach, using classes and objects but keeping it chill and all...

We’ll use a std::vector to store our nodes. Each node doesn't need a pointer to the next one. Instead, we just keep track of the indices in the vector. It's like having a list of names where you just know who's next in line.

Here's a quick example to show you what I mean:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Node {
public:
    int data;

    Node(int data) : data(data) {}
};

class LinkedList {
private:
    std::vector<Node> nodes;

public:
    void addNode(int data) {
        nodes.emplace_back(data);
    }

    void printList() {
        for (auto &node : nodes) {
            std::cout << node.data << " -> ";
        }
        std::cout << "null\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    LinkedList myList;
    myList.addNode(5);
    myList.addNode(10);
    myList.addNode(15);

    myList.printList();
    return 0;
}
```

In this version, Node is super simple. Just the data, no next node pointer. The LinkedList class uses a std::vector to hold these Node objects. When we add a node, we just add it to the vector. The order in the vector is the order of the nodes in the list.

When printing, we just loop through the vector. No pointer mess, no complicated linking. Just adding to a list and looping through it.

Remember, this approach is a bit of a workaround. It’s not your traditional linked list. But it's cleaner and simpler, especially if you're not a fan of pointers...

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's possible to implement a linked list in C++ using classes and objects instead of raw pointers. In an object-oriented approach, you can define a class for the linked list itself and another class for the nodes of the list. Here's a simple example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Node {
public:
    int data;
    Node* next;

    Node(int value) : data(value), next(nullptr) {}
};

class LinkedList {
private:
    Node* head;

public:
    LinkedList() : head(nullptr) {}

    void append(int value) {
        Node* newNode = new Node(value);

        if (head == nullptr) {
            head = newNode;
        } else {
            Node* current = head;
            while (current->next != nullptr) {
                current = current->next;
            }
            current->next = newNode;
        }
    }

    void display() {
        Node* current = head;
        while (current != nullptr) {
            std::cout << current->data << " ";
            current = current->next;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    ~LinkedList() {
        Node* current = head;
        while (current != nullptr) {
            Node* next = current->next;
            delete current;
            current = next;
        }
        head = nullptr;
    }
};

int main() {
    LinkedList myList;
    myList.append(1);
    myList.append(2);
    myList.append(3);

    std::cout << "Linked List: ";
    myList.display();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Node class member next is a pointer, so what is the point of this answer?

Comment: So `Node* next` isn't a pointer? Please explain.